# Save dictionary into list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is the code:

```
score = ['10','20','30']
name = ['Joe','HA','Sue']
fm = ['F','M','F']
event = [] 
for i in score:
    i = i + 'points'
    # event.append(i)
for i in name:
    i = i + '_ss'
for i in fm:
    i = i + 'nn'
```

I want to save the data like below:
Please tell me the type of event is dict or list?
And how to write code to save like this way

```
 "event": [{"score": "10point", "name": "Joe_ss", "FM": "Fnn"},
           {"score": "20point", "name": "Ha_ss", "FM": "Mnn"},
           {"score": "30point", "name": "Sue_ss", "FM": "Fnn"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> score = ['10','20','30']
>>> name = ['Joe','HA','Sue']
>>> fm = ['F','M','F']
>>> event = [{'score': s + 'point', 'name': n+'_ss', 'FM': f + 'nn'} for s, n, f in zip(score, name, fm)]
>>> event
 [{'score': '10point', 'name': 'Joe_ss', 'FM': 'Fnn'}, 
  {'score': '20point', 'name': 'HA_ss', 'FM': 'Mnn'}, 
  {'score': '30point', 'name': 'Sue_ss', 'FM': 'Fnn'}]
```

Comment: Can you teach me how to save this to variable event? event =[{"score": "10point", "name": "Joe_ss", "FM": "Fnn"},
           {"score": "20point", "name": "Ha_ss", "FM": "Mnn"},
           {"score": "30point", "name": "Sue_ss", "FM": "Fnn"}] This is more skillful I can't understand